# ionic http get doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

My project back-end is implemented with VS with the port number 26309 and I am implementing my front-end with ionic in notepad++ .

My problem is that the controller can't retrieve data through :`$http.get("http://localhost:26309/api/User/getAll/")`.

**SOLUTION**

I solved the problem by :

1- adding in the config.xml the permission `<allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>`

2-installing cordova-plugin-whitelist `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

3-add control-allow-origin extention to chrome :https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en-US

And finally : specifying the type of data returned by the back-end controller by adding this code to my Global.asax in Application_start method :

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting =
                Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: What is your console output?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$http.get('http://localhost:26309/api/User/getAll/')
   .success(function(data){
       //your code
   }
    .error(function(error){
       //your code
   }
```

Comment: Can you try this,

$http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:26309/api/User/getAll/'})
  .success(function(data) {
    $scope.User = data;
  });

Answer (score 0):

You use ionic. Did you tried this on a device? 
Because you will never reach your server on your pc with `localhost` from a device. You have to use an `ip address` or `domain name`.

Answer (score 0):

Localhost points to the local device, not your development machine.  @Simon is correct.

Thanks,
Dan